# Cut out sprite from PNG image IsvisibleFrom camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, sprite, visible

I'm trying to make a 2D cut PNG image that I use as a sprite gameObject to be visible when in the field of view of my camera. Note that the sprites can be projected all around the player, like pictures, in a 3D environment, it is not a 2D oriented game.

The problem is that the Renderer seems to be used as a rectangle like the PNG gameObject.
To picture my problem;
The following 2 images return true (isVisibleFrom) regardless if the actual "visible" sprite is in the FOV or not..
[image]
[image]

This is the png I'm actually using as a gameObject:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I think that what is taken into account is the entire "gameobject" containing the sprite renderer and not only the drawn sprite... how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Go in to your camera and change it from orthographic to perspective.

Comment: It is already perspective (It just doesn't seem to be as the screenshot was taken from a different angle).